# Spark UDF exception when accessing broadcast variable

Tags: apache-spark, broadcast, udf, notserializableexception

I'm having difficulty accessing a `scala.collection.immutable.Map` from inside a spark UDF.

I'm broadcasting the map

```
val browserLangMap = sc.broadcast (Source.fromFile(browserLangFilePath).getLines.map(_.split(,)).map(e => (e(0).toInt,e(1))).toMap)
```

creating UDF that access the map

```
def addBrowserCode = udf((browserLang:Int) => if(browserLangMap.value.contains(browserLang)) browserLangMap.value(browserLang) else "")`
```

using the UDF to add new column

```
val joinedDF = rawDF.join(broadcast(geoDF).as("GEO"), $"start_ip" === $"GEO.start_ip_num", "left_outer")
                        .withColumn("browser_code", addBrowserCode($"browser_language"))
                        .selectExpr(getSelectQuery:_*)
```

full stack trace --> https://www.dropbox.com/s/p1d5322fo9cxro6/stack_trace.txt?dl=0

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
        at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:304)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:294)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:122)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2055)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1857)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$MetaDataSchema$
Serialization stack:
        - object not serializable (class: $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$MetaDataSchema$, value: $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$MetaDataSchema$@30b4ba52)
        - field (class: $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, name: MetaDataSchema$module, type: class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$MetaDataSchema$)
        - object (class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ScalaUDF, UDF(browser_language#235))
        - field (class: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.If, name: falseValue, type: class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Expression)
        - object (class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.If, if (isnull(browser_language#235)) null else UDF(browser_language#235))
        - field (class: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Alias, name: child, type: class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Expression)
        - object (class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Alias, if (isnull(browser_language#235)) null else UDF(browser_language#235) AS browser_language#507)
        - object (class org.apache.spark.OneToOneDependency, org.apache.spark.OneToOneDependency@5ae38c4e)
        - writeObject data (class: scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon)
        - object (class scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon, List(org.apache.spark.OneToOneDependency@5ae38c4e))
        - field (class: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD, name: org$apache$spark$rdd$RDD$$dependencies_, type: interface scala.collection.Seq)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:301)
        ... 80 more
```

I know its the access to broadcast Map that is causing this. When I remove reference to that in the UDF there are no exception.

```
def addBrowserCode = udf((browserLang:Int) => browserLang.toString())  //Test UDF without accessing broadcast Map and it works
```

Spark version 1.6

Comment: Could you: a) format the question - it is really hard to read, b) provide types for all objects c) provide example input d) explain how you execute this (`spark-shell`, `spark-submit`)

Comment: I'm sorry you found question hard to read. I was trying to make a simpler example today and accidentally found the solution :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found this to be a strange behavior with ":paste" in spark shell. This happens only when I paste my entire code in a single multi-line paste with :paste.

The same code works perfectly if I paste the broadcast and UDF creation first and then paste the join+saveToFile in a separate :paste.

May be scala shell issue. I don't know.

Comment: Some oddities still here

Answer (score 1):

The root cause relates to declaring `val sc: SparkContext = spark.sparkContext` in the code for the broadcast variable. If the code runs on a spark-shell, sc is already available by default. Declaring sc twice (one by default and one in the code) causes this "Task not serializable" problem. Therefore, unlike the previous answer claimed, there is no issue with the spark-shell. Just temporarily remove the SparkContext declaration while in the spark-shell, the code will be OK.

Comment: From his code I don't see he is re-declaring `sc`. He is broadcasting the variables in the spark context already given by spark-shell.